# Get form onsubmit to return true from addEventListener function

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Here's the problem. I have a form with various inputs and a submit button. When the user hits "submit", it waits for an "addEventListener" event to fire (usually within 3 seconds). I need the form to then properly submit the form (preferably without using AJAX).

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    var ele=document.getElementById('audio');
    ele.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
        // After doing some stuff here, how do I get the parent function to
        // return true so that the form can be submitted?
    });
    // I put this here so that the browser is forced to wait for the
    // "addEventListener" event
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a boolean variable that indicates whether or not to submit the form.  Set it to `true` from the `canplay` handler:

```
(function () {
    var shouldSubmit = false;
    $('#form').submit(function(){ 
        var ele=document.getElementById('audio'); 
        ele.addEventListener('canplay',function(){ 
            // do some stuff here
            shouldSubmit = true;
        }); 
        return shouldSubmit; 
    }); 
})();
```

This will cause that after the `canplay` event has fired, the form can be submitted.  If you want the form to be submitted immediately when the `canplay` event fires, call `form.submit()` instead:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){ 
    var ele=document.getElementById('audio'); 
    var form = this;
    ele.addEventListener('canplay',function(){ 
        // do some stuff here
        form.submit();
    }); 
    return false; 
});
```